# Comparing Star Formation rate in different galaxies

Tags: observational-astronomy, astrophysics, stellar-astrophysics, high-energy-astrophysics

I was looking for some scale to compare my result of [star formation rate](https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/star-formation+rate) in order to find out whether it is moderate or high or low, but I couldn't find any scale. Is there any paper related to such scale where Star formation rate form minimum to maximum of each galaxy is given and once can compare their result with scale.

I found that one of dwarf galaxies has 0.2 star formation rate, but since I don't have scale to compare, thus I have no clue whether it is high or low or moderate? What is the maximum star formation rate?

Comment: Interesting question. For Star Formation Rate, are you using total Solar Mass of new stars per year or some other measure? Please clarify.

Comment: @ConnorGarcia yest It is total solar Mass per year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not being an expert in star formation, I found a [well-written paper summary](https://astrobites.org/2014/09/30/measuring-galaxy-star-formation/) from which I conclude that **typical star formation rates range between $6 \ldots 24 M_\odot / yr$.**

The blog quotes the following graph
[image] by M. Boquien, V. Buat, and V. Perret, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.5792

> In this paper we investigate in isolation the impact of a variable star formation history on the measurement of the SFR.
> We combine 23 state-of-the-art hydrodynamical simulations of 1<z<2 galaxies on the main sequence with the cigale spectral energy distribution modelling code. This allows us to generate synthetic spectra every 1 Myr for each simulation, taking the stellar populations and the nebular emission into account. Using these spectra, we estimate the SFR from classical estimators which we compare with the true SFR we know from the simulations.

In summary: To me, $0.2 M_\odot / yr$ looks rather small, but I cannot judge whether it is unrealistic for a dwarf galaxy.